# Datasource monitoring

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using tomcat to deploy my application. DataSource (OracleDataSource) is defined as a Spring bean. I'm interested in monitoring datasource connection pool. Are there any tools available to monitor datasource?

Answer (score 4):

You could install either LambdaProbe or it's fork [PSIProbe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) which will give you [details such as this](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/screenshots/full/datasources.png).

Both are open source products and usage is very similar to the Tomcat Manager.

LambdaProbe does not seem to be maintained any more. PSIProbe definitely has [datasource collector info](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/psiprobe/beans/stats/collectors/DatasourceStatsCollectorBean.java?r=263)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [JavaMelody](http://javamelody.googlecode.com) (opensource) to monitor datasources from Spring, JNDI, etc.
For example, you can have [graphics](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/Screenshots) of jdbc connections or statistics on sql requests.